# How to inflate an optionsMenu vertically on a button click

Tags: android

I'm trying to inflate an options menu on a button click. 
I managed to inflate it  using `openOptionsMenu();` in button's `onClick event`(as we are using a layout with custom fields like ImageView, Textbox on the action bar).
But the menu is inflated on the bottom. Right now my menu is inflated like below image:
[image]

I want it to be opened vertically(some thing like below).

[image]

How can I do it?

Below are my code samples:

### Main Activity:

```
private Button optionsMenu;
optionsMenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.optionsMenu);
```

### In onCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);
optionsMenu.setOnClickListener(menuInflate);

 private OnClickListener menuInflate = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Uri uri;
        Intent i;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                uri = Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com");
                i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            case R.id.option2:
                uri = Uri.parse("tel:92345678");
                i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

### options_menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/option1" android:title="About"
        android:orderInCategory="101" android:showAsAction="withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/option2" android:title="Help"
        android:orderInCategory="102" android:showAsAction="withText" />
</menu>
```

### menu_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/content_bg_color">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_sub_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip">
        <com.abc.ThirdParty.SmartImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="54dip"
            android:layout_height="54dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/portrait"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_text_show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_profile_image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/optionsmenu_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_options_menu"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your question is not clear, right now your menu is inflated like what?

Comment: the two buttons at the bottom? about and help?

Comment: @AshishRanjan yes. when i click on the image, the menu if inflated like the image with about and help buttons at the bottom

Comment: you're doing it the wrong way, let me update the answer

Comment: @AshishRanjan sure. thanks.

Comment: can you add your custom toolbar `xml` code to the question?

Comment: @AshishRanjan updated. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

To show the menu items on click, set their `showAsAction` attribute to `never` as described in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) :

> never : Never place this item in the app bar. Instead, list the item in the app bar's overflow menu.

So set this for the items that you want in the overflow menu :

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

**UPDATE**

Also, remove the `optionsMenu` image (the one with three dots) that you've put on the `Toolbar` manually. `Android` will put that icon itself  if there are menu items with `showAsAction` attribute set to `never` or there isn't enough space in the `Toolbar` to show the items.

and remove these methods from the `onClickListener` of your image and put them inside your `Activity` class :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

**UPDATE #2**

If you want a custom `Toolbar` with overflow menu button, there's no need to put a `Button`(with 3 dots icon) for that. If you want to customize the `Toolbar` put your whole layout code inside `Toolbar` in the xml and set that as the Activity's Toolbar inside `onCreate` like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
        <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/content_bg_color">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_sub_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">
            <com.abc.ThirdParty.SmartImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="54dip"
                android:layout_height="54dip"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/portrait"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username_text_show"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_profile_image"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then set the toolbar in the `onCreate` like this :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and don't worry about the overflow menu button, it'll be added automatically in the cases discussed above.

Here's the output of this code :

[image: overflow menu screenshot]

Comment: Tried this. But still the same way it is inflated(below).

Comment: optionsMenu varaiable is yout image with three dots right?

Comment: yes. the highlighted one in red color. Its an image.

Comment: Hey ashish. Thanks for the answer.(Sorry for the confusion as I didnt add few details) I know android will put it on using menu inflater. But my team is using a custom action bar with profile image(imageView) and user name(textbox)  because of which I had to use an image similar to the android's default button.

Answer (score 0):

Change your options_menu.xml like this

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="About"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Help"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```

And in your Activity..

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option1) {

                //perform with Option1 here

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option2) {

                //perform with Option2 here
        } 

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

it will automatically put the button that you want no need to put manually!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the confusion. I forgot to add few details. edited the question.